# Get Flickr Sets

Tags: php, javascript, api, flickr

*Usual stuff, Googled forever, looked on here, no help. Yet.*

What I want is to list the sets of photos I have on Flickr. Nice & simple, it would seem.
I want the 'title image' (the one used as the thumb for it on Flickr its self), the title and URL. Can't be that hard, can it?

The language of choice is **PHP** (5.1.6), or **JS** (*jQuery* if possible). Both are good.

Answer (score 1):

Using [flickr.photos.search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) method of the API with your user_id does not work ?

For PHP, you have a PEAR-based package [here](http://code.iamcal.com/php/flickr/readme.htm) and another library at http://phpflickr.com/. Should be enough to get through it.

EDIT :

For minimal implementation you should use [stream_context_create()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) with HTTP headers, use `fopen()` with this context and build a XMLRPC request by hand as a text variable that you will send. Answer from the socket will be your data

For the API, use [flickr.photosets.getList](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getList.html)

CODE EXAMPLE (you need a valid api key for flickr)

```
<?php
$apiKey = '';
$userID = '';
$url = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key='
    .$apiKey.'&user_id='.$userID.'&format=json';
$options = Array('http' => Array('method' => 'GET'));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$object = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: The search documentation doesent seem to mention sets...

I did look at http://phpflickr.com/ before, it just looks like a lot of overhead for one small piece of functionality that I want.

Comment: Thanks for updating that, Serty. You wouldn't have any sample code, or links to some would you?

Comment: Once again, thanks Serty. file_get_contents is disabled on our servers, so I've has to use Curl, but this definitely got me going. I'm now seeing set titles on my page. I'll post up my final code when I'm done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

see also http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.flickr.html for a nice tidy wrapper